# Where could I ask questions about the name and availability of a job in a given country?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding the availability and name of a specific job in a given country as I'm planning to move there in the future. While I do have a friend who lives there, they are unable to find this job listed anywhere and are unsure of how to translate the name of the job, and it would be rather strange if the job didn't exist there at all. As such, I was thinking of asking about what this job could be called and if it's available in the given country here on Stack Exchange.

Where on Stack Exchange would this question best be asked?

For what it's worth, the country is Sweden and the language is Swedish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A site to check on is [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) since their [What topics can I ask about here?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page specifically states

> Education and work seeking questions for a person migrating from a different country (please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and make sure your question is not too broad, or too localized though)

However, before possibly posting there, I suggest to first go through the rest of their [Help Center](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help) information, try to determine what appropriate tag(s) already exist there (e.g., [Sweden](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweden), and possibly [job-hunting](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-hunting)), search (e.g., using the site search with just the tag(s) of interest) for any similar questions there (including to determine if your question has already been asked) to help determine how to best phrase your question, etc.